# Project Variables in Eclipse Post-Build Script

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, scripting

I'm trying to run a post-build python script in Eclipse. By explicitly naming the path to the python script, I am able to get it to run correctly. However, when I attempt to use the Eclipse project variable `${PROJECT_LOC}`, it's unable to resolve the correct path.

What I've tried entering, with no success, into the post-build script section of Eclipse's build settings:

```
python.exe ${PROJECT_LOC}\script.py
Results: can't open file '\script.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` 

python.exe PROJECT_LOC\script.py
Results: can't open file 'PROJECT_LOC\script.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Again, it works when I explicitly define the path to the script like so:

```
python.exe C:\somepath\script.py
```

It seems to not register the eclipse `PROJECT_LOC` variable. Is it possible to use Eclipse's variables when calling a pre/post-build command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution and wanted to post an answer in case others would like to do something similar.

As long as the Python executable location and script location are in your system environment path variable, you can simply add `cmd.exe /c MyScript.py` in the Eclipse Post-build steps command field located in properties under `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Steps`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this one too, not understanding why Eclipse would not translate that environment variable, but I think that the right one to use, or at least it worked for me, is this one:

`${ProjDirPath}`

I had a similar issue, with the `PROJECT_LOC` environment variable not working. I noticed that the command had `${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}` as a parameter at the end of my line, something that was not defined in my list of variables. I searched a bit and found a lot of macros in this [Texas Instruments page](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Project_Macros), and that's how I found `$ProjDirPath`

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issue here adding quotes to the script path:

post build cmd:

```
python3 "${ProjDirPath}/path_to_my_script/script.py" args
```